# Ошибка компиляции APK

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

После установки windows 10 установил unity 2020.3.18f но при попытке компиляции на андроид выдаёт ошибки. Устанавливал другую версию unity 2020.3.10f проблема такая же. Создал новый проект, специально для проверки. Скачал sdk, jdk (1.8.0_77), ndk (r19) ошибок стало поменьше, но остались (скрины ниже). Как избавиться от этих ошибок чтобы успешно собрать apk?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Исправил ошибку установив Unity 2019.4.30, выбрал установленные самой Unity sdk jdk  и т.д и далее нажал это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]